# Bulk-convert Word Perfect to LibreOffice Format?

Tags: convert

Is there a way to bulk-convert old Word Perfect word processing files to LibreOffice Writer format in Ubuntu? It's apparently possible to convert them one at a time, but when you have over a decade of of files, that would be a large task. The files are currently on an air-gapped WinXP machine maintained for the files.

Also, if converted either individually or bulk, would that leave the meta-data (origin date) in place or would it change it to today?

Edit: For the purpose here, "bulk import" would be acceptable as long as the files are readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unoconv](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/) (or on [github](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv))

It is packaged, you can install it via:

(Debian/Ubuntu-based)

```
apt install unoconv
```

(...or RedHat-based, wrong forum I know)

```
yum install unoconv
```

Then run:

```
unoconv -f odt file1.wps file2.wps ... fileN.wps
```

**Extra info:**

Check the list of possible formats (wps is listed):

```
unoconv --show
```

unoconv can run standalone or as a listening service. I use it as a listening service for on-the-fly pdf conversion for an internal doc management tool. I'm happy to provide a systemd unit file if that's of interest to you, but probably overkill for your current needs.

**Regarding the Metadata query:**

I'm out of my depth here, you will definitely get new file access/modify/change times with unoconv, perhaps this thread can help you out though:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630695/linux-modify-file-modify-access-change-time

Comment: Your first link is broken. The link provided by `apt-cache show` is http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/  .

Comment: thanks for the heads up, it looks like he changed the repo name on github. I've updated and added your link too -